# Plotting polar and scatter plot together

Tags: r, ggplot2

I already plot polar and seasonal plot with a10-antidiabetic drug sales from forecast package. You can see code and plot below:

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
library(fpp2)
library(gridExtra)


PLOT_SEAS<-ggseasonplot(a10, polar=TRUE) +
  ylab("$ million") +
  ggtitle("Polar seasonal plot: antidiabetic drug sales")


PLOT_LAG<-gglagplot(a10,seasonal = TRUE,set.lags = 1:12)+
  ggtitle(" Lagged scatterplots") 

grid.arrange(PLOT_SEAS,PLOT_LAG, nrow=1)
```

Output from those lines of code is plot below, which don't look very well.

[image]

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem with grid.arrange function and make this charts with the same height ?

Comment: Your years appear to be categorical, not numbers. That would reduce the legend on the left. I prefer the `patchwork` function over `grid.arrange`, but I don't know if it will change the relative layout between the two.

Comment: Thank you. I will check patchwork

Comment: Just a point of pedantry here; if you're using lines, that is not a scatterplot but a lineplot.